Incrementing counter in NewRelic from Java Agent. Can't query for it with NRQL
Background
I have a Kotlin project, with v8.11.0 of the Java NewRelic Agent and API.
I send some custom metrics to NR already, with the CustomEvents API, like this:
    fun recordCustomEvent(name: String, attributes: Map<String, Any>) {
        NewRelic.getAgent().insights.recordCustomEvent(name, attributes)
    }

This works fine. It reports and I can query it.
Goal
To use the counter datatype.
I have the following function:
    fun incrementCounter(increment: Int = 1) {
        val metricName = "Custom/Foo/Bar"
        NewRelic.incrementCounter(metricName, increment)
    }

And I call it a bunch of times, but I can't seem to query for it in NR's interface.
I'm trying the query: FROM Metric SELECT * WHERE metricName = 'Custom/Foo/Bar', and variations of it, but nothing.
The metricName has auto-complete, so if anything existed resembling "foo", I would have seen it. Is it not in Metric at all?
Question
How do I increment a counter programatically, and query for it with NRQL?

They should show in Metrics Explorer for the application you are monitoring.
And to search using NRQL, have you tried searching for timesliceMetricName?
FROM Metric SELECT * WHERE metricTimesliceName = 'Custom/Foo/Bar'

